# How to make non-ascii-armored public key from ascii-armored secret key

Tags: security, gnupg, apparmor

I have

old key pair (GnuPG keys), both only ascii-armored

1 fresh Ubuntu-Desktop 14.04 installation

How can I make a non-ascii armored public key from the old secret key?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to import and subsequently export they key *without* using the `--ascii` flag.

1. Import the key

   ```
   gpg --import 4secret-key.asc
   ```
2. If you don't know the key id, look it up

   ```
   gpg --list-secret-keys
   ```
3. Export the public key, storing it in a file

   ```
   gpg --export [key-id] >public-key.gpg
   ```

If you don't want to import the key to your keyring, set `$GNUPGHOME` to something temporary, eg. by running `export GNUPGHOME=/tmp/gnupg` before the commands given above. Deleting the folder afterwards might be reasonable.